# What're the differences between these - There + "be supposed to be" or "appear(s) to be" or "seem(s) to be"

Tags: word-choice, usage

What are the differences between these:
There +

1. "is supposed to be"
2. "appear(s) to be"
3. "seem(s) to be"

I can't distinguish those usages because those seem to be quite similar to me in meaning.

First, what does this sentence imply?

> There is supposed to be a letter for me here.

Is it saying that the letter should be here because someone said it would be here? Or is supposed to be here?

And I know "seems to be" and "appears to be" are almost similar, but I think there are the exact moments when you use them differently.
Like which sounds more formal or polite or in which situation you don't use this, something like that.

Comment: Welcome to ELL, jeheecheon. We expect people to do a little research before asking a question: in this case you could look up these words in a good dictionary, for example https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/supposed If you are still unclear, please edit your question to add details of your research, preferably with links, and explain what exactly you still don't understand.

Comment: Yes, "There is supposed to be a letter for me" means what you say; you have been told that there is one. _Appear to be_ and _seem to be_ have much the same meaning and register. You would be more likely to use _appear_ of something you can see. "There is a figure in the distance. It appears to be a man carrying a suitcase."